# Expo Google login not work in Test flight in IOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, cross-platform

I'm face such a critical issue in expo google sing-in in app. In the development mode it's work fine but when i'm upload app in test flight it's give URL mis-match error in app.

I'm using expo-google-app-auth library in app. Please anyone help me to overcome this issues.

Thank You in advance.

Stay Safe.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. I was trying to solve this for 2 days! I re-read the documentation
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/google/
and found that I was missing one line of code!

> const { type, accessToken, user } = await Google.logInAsync({
> iosClientId: <YOUR_IOS_CLIENT_ID_FOR_EXPO>,   androidClientId:
> <YOUR_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID_FOR_EXPO>,   iosStandaloneAppClientId:
> <YOUR_IOS_CLIENT_ID>,   androidStandaloneAppClientId:
> <YOUR_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID>, });

i was missing this:

> iosStandaloneAppClientId: <YOUR_IOS_CLIENT_ID>
>
> i only had iosClientId: